# $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(i+3)(i+4)} = \frac{n}{4(n+4)}$ (prove by induction)

Tags: induction

I'm having some difficulty proving by induction the following statement.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(i+3)(i+4)} = \frac{n}{4(n+4)}$$

I have shown that $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(i+3)(i+4)} = \frac{n}{4(n+4)}$ holds for $n=1$ (equals $\frac{1}{20}$) , but I am getting stuck on the induction step.

As far as I know I have to show $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(i+3)(i+4)} = \frac{n}{4(n+4)}$$ 
implies
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(i+3)(i+4)} = \frac{n+1}{4(n+5)}$$

To do this I think I should add the number $\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+5)}$ to $\frac{n}{4(n+4)}$ and see if it gives $\frac{n+1}{4(n+5)}$ , if I am not mistaken.

When trying to do that however I get stuck. I have:

$$\frac{n}{4(n+4)} +\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+5)} = \frac{n(n+4)(n+5)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} + \frac{4(n+4)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} = \frac{n(n+4)(n+5)+4(n+4)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} = \frac{n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}$$

However beyond this point I don't know how to reach  $\frac{n+1}{4(n+5)}$ I always just end up at the starting point of that calculation.

So I think that either my approach must be wrong or I am missing some trick how to simplify $$\frac{(n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}$$

I would be very grateful for any help, as this is a task on a preparation sheet for the next exam and I don't know anyone, that has a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\frac{n^2+5n+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\frac{(n+4)(n+1)}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\frac{n+1}{4(n+5)}$$

Comment: Wow thank you I simply did not see that n^2 +5n+4 = (n+4)(n+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\dfrac{n^2+5n+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\dfrac{(n+1)(n+4)}{4(n+4)(n+5)}$$

This simplifies to $\dfrac {n+1}{4(n+5)}$ and you want to substitute $n$ for $n+1$ for $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n}{4(n+4)} +\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+5)} = \frac{n(n+4)(n+5)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} + \frac{4(n+4)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} = \frac{n(n+4)(n+5)+4(n+4)}{4(n+4)^2(n+5)} = \frac{(n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}$$

Last expression can be simplified by $n+4$

$$\frac{n(n+5)+4}{4(n+4)(n+5)}=\frac{(n+1)}{4(n+5)}=\frac{(n+1)}{4((n+1)+4)}$$

Comment: Thank you, I simply failed to see how to simplify correctly. I guess I need more practice.

Comment: yw Viceh   @idk ypu are right but I leave it that way I want  to show that it is exactly the formula with $n+1$ i,n place of n